# How to calculate z-score of row in a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am new to coding.
Trying to calculate the z-score of my dataframe in python using scipy.stats.zscore.
I wrote:

```
df_snv= df.drop(['Wavelength','Mean'],axis=1).apply(stats.zscore,axis=0);
```

Here, 'Wavelength' and 'Mean' are the columns I don't need in my calculations.But this gives me the wrong result.

Things I also tried using axis=1 but this makes all the values as NaN.

```
df_snv= df.drop(['Wavelength','Mean'],axis=1).apply( lambda x: (x.df.mean(axis=1))/df.std(axis=1) )
```

Without any success. Can anyone tell me a simple way to do this? Thanks for your patience.

P.S.: the dataframe I am working with has a column called Wavelength and all others are Absorbance values, I want the SNV of each absorbance value for a particular Wavelength.

Comment: Could you share code where you build your dataframe (or a subset)? That makes it easier to understand your problem

Comment: @pizza_slice I take NIR spectroscopy data from the Stellar Whiz software in .ABS format and then convert it to excel columns.